# Index to speed up ActiveAdmin index page

Tags: postgresql, activeadmin

We have million of records and thus Model.count is quite slow.
Active Admin relies on model.count to do pagination in its index page, and in our case it results in very slow response time under load.

What kind of index can be added so that it speed up Model.count? or any alternative solution to speed up pagination calculation for Active Admin index page?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
index pagination_total: false do
```

In ond Active Admin this doesn't work and you should do:

Gemfile

```
gem 'dont_you_count' # below activeadmin gem
```

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config| config.dont_count = ['product', 'order'] end
```

The total count will be set to 2 million and it will break last pagination button but it is better than having the server overloaded.

Comment: Interesting: `dont_you_count` is new to me. The [issue it was supposed to address](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3847) is closed. I'm wondering if there is a regression, but no-one has reported further problems recently on GitHub.